# Extract html source code with selenium xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to extract data from a table that is very long. For every row in the table I want to copy a specific HTML code.

My HTML source code (which I fully want to extract) looks like:

```
<div class="relative">
                  <div id="stats9526577" class="dark"></div>
                  <img src="/detaljer-1.gif" onmouseover="view_stats(9526577, 14, 13, 4, 7, 10, 8, 6, 3);">
                </div>
```

I tried the python code:

```
data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="relative"]')
```

How can I print the above HTML source code in python using xpath?

Comment: Assuming the xpath is correct. you could do data.innerHTML

Comment: _I tried the python code_ Alright, and what happened? What is the issue?

Comment: Please do not repost extremely similar and connected questions multiple times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61291183/web-scraping-through-pagination-list, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61298480/extract-html-source-code-without-any-class-or-div-python-selenium.

Answer (score 1):

To print the `html` of the elements matching the `xpath`, you can use [`get_attribute()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) with `innerHTML` as argument, i.e.:

```
data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="relative"]')
for el in data:
    html = el.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    print(html)
```